# Does Google Drive replicate files before uploading?

Tags: file-system, google-drive, uploads

When I upload files by Google Drive on my Samsung S4, I get full storage notification, so I need to know if G-Drive replicate any file on Android before or after uploading it.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to analyse if Google Drive and your notification are related. Like the size of file you want to upload or your total storage size or your occupied storage size etc.

Comment: But why would google drive *replicate* your file, which means, you'll end up with two copies of same file on phone, then extra copy in the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say so. When uploading large files (~200 MB), I have gotten "Low memory" errors, even though I had over 500MB (out of 16 GB internal) free.

This notification would go a few seconds after the upload completed.

Typically, about 300 MB causes low memory errors for me. I have a Moto G3 running the CrDroid custom ROM, 6.0.1 (Marshmallow).

I don't know the Google Drive code, but it certainly seems to be so. Whether the data is cached as app data or on the SD card, I can't comment.

Answer (score 0):

One can't really know what Google Drive does without going through all the codes but there is no need for it to do so. It's a simple upload procedure. I believe your problem is not related to it.